# About crossdomain.xml file and flash

Tags: flash, dns, cross-domain

As you know, a flash browser application needs a crossdomain.xml file on the cross domain web server to access files on it, and for some well known web service, no crossdomain.xml file is available. For example Google's spreadsheets or Amazon's SimpleDB.

Let me give the following question, but if the question is inappropriate here please point out so.

I have a domain name, say "domain.com", with no actually running web server. Using DNS settings, can I use my domain name to represent 2 web servers, one for downloading my flash application and one for redirecting requests to the cross domain web server, for example to  google's site or to amazon's AWS site?

If yes, can it help my flash browser application to access the latter web site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds a bit confusing and I am not sure whether it is feasible. Anyway usually we use a proxy php file in the same server which will fetch data from other servers.

http://xmlrpcflash.mattism.com/proxy_info.php

You can modify this and use for your requirement.